# Infragistics UltraGrid (9.2) count Band after DataSource is set

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

In an inherited UltraGrid I would like know how many Bands the grid contains after I set a new value on `base.DataSource`. How do I find that count?

Thanks

-a-

/*****Added screendump*****/

(code is not my property so I've scrambled away some possible trade secrets)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the new dataSource object to the DataSource property of the UltraGrid you could verify the count like:

ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands.Count

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I don't get at all  what I expect from that property. As DataSource I set a IList<Stoff> whith one object in it. This object has three children, also of type Stoff, in a property IList<Stoff>. Somewhere between 'DataSource = myList' and a InitializeLayout eventhandler the 'DisplayLayout.Band.Count' jump up to 100... Any idea?

Comment: It seems to me that your IList<Stoff> is selfrelated. So once you have set it as a DataSource the Bands count will increase from 0 to its maximum number of the Bands - 100. The UltraGrid will display the same hierarchy that comes from your IList object. You have the possibility to restrict the maximum band depth to the desired number. The most suitable place for doing so would be in the InitializeLayout event and set there the following code line: e.Layout.MaxBandDepth = 8; Doing so the UltraGrid will create only this number of Bands for you.

Comment: I does reference itself, but when the referenced object is null it still creactes a band - is this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **PropertyChanged** event of the base class *UltraControlBase*:

```
public void Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    ultraWinGrid.PropertyChanged += new Infragistics.Win.PropertyChangedEventHandler(ultraWinGrid_PropertyChanged);
}
void ultraWinGrid_PropertyChanged(object sender, Infragistics.Win.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Infragistics.Shared.PropChangeInfo pinfo = e.ChangeInfo;
    try
    {
        // moving through the trigger stack
        while (pinfo!=null)
        {
            if (Equals(pinfo.PropId, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyIds.DataSource))
            {
                int newBandCount = this.ultraWinGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands.Count;
                /// your code here
            }
            pinfo=pinfo.Trigger;
        }
    }
    catch
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the issue remains. See above comments and screendump.

Comment: Bands.Count=100 means that grid now have 100 band total including underlying bands. How many items there are in your datasource? Is it hierarchical? It looks like UltraGrid create separate band for every child in Stoff object.

Comment: Hi. There is only one (for now) 'Stoff' in the datasource at the topmost level. However the Stoff object contains a list - 'IList<Stoff> SubStoffs' with more Stoff-objects, i.e. the 2. band, which in turn can in tehory (but not in practice) contain more Stoff-objects in their lists and so on and so on. It seems that the UltraGrid keeps on creating bands for each list in each object until it reaches 100 bands. But why is this when the Stoff-objects in the 2. band in the grid has their 'SubStoffs = null'? How do I tell UltraGrid: _hey you - don't create more bands when the list is null!_?

Comment: Hmm, i can not tell you exact way to tune this behavior. Did you set **DataMember** property?

Comment: If I set `DataMember = "SubStoffs";` or `SetDataBinding(value, "SubStoffs");` in my overridden UltraGrids set DataSource property nothing is displayed... Really don't understand this DataMember thing in this context... What is it suppose to do when my DataSource is the previously described IList<Stoff>-object?